# Hide section completely when no children available | Isotope.js Filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am creating an application and using the [isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) filter library.

I have multiple sections with headers which under each one there is an isotope container like this:

```
<div class="main-items-container-a">
    <h2>Items Category 1</h2>
    <div class="items-container">
        <div class="items a">A</div>        
        <div class="items a">A</div>
        <div class="items b">B</div>
        <div class="items c">C</div>
        <div class="items c">C</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main-items-container-b">
    <h2>Items Category 2</h2>
    <div class="items-container">
        <div class="items">A</div>        
        <div class="items">A</div>
        <div class="items">B</div>
        <div class="items">C</div>
        <div class="items">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am also creating filters for the above items and I would like that when all items are filtered and no more items are available in the section, the whole section including the title `h2` gets hidden. Vice versa when it then needs to show.

I did try to achieve something using the following event available by Isotope, however I couldn't get to the parent of length 0 of the filtered items.

```
$grid.on( 'arrangeComplete', function( event, filteredItems ) {
  console.log( filteredItems.length );
});
```

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/se8bg70x/) to demonstrate this.

Can someone guide me to what I am doing wrong to achieve this.